# iOS- How to create a modular SDK for user

Tags: ios, sdk, cloud

I'm a SDK developer, my SDK wants to provider a simpler way to use more third-part SDKs such as share SDKs(google+,twitter, ), pay SDKs, map SDKs(google, AMap). As common, I should include all these SDKs lib files to my project and build my SDK, this makes my SDK very big. So, how can I compile my SDK, when my user add one third-part lib himself, then my SDK have the function, when he remove the lib, my SDK lose the function. Is this possible and anyone can share your experience.

Comment: Cocoapods is a good way to lighter my framework, but what I want is something like this: I have a core framework which include my logic to handle third-part SDKs, then user A wants twitter share function, he put my core framework and twitter sdk together, and he use my framework can easily using twitter sdk.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Cocoapods](http://cocoapods.org) to do this. You have to learn how to create a public library, then in your pod spec file you can specify [frameworks](http://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#frameworks) or [dependencies](http://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#dependency).

Comment: You mean I add the third-part SDKs using Cocoapods in my project and when I release, I put the dependencies in pod spec?  But I want to release my SDK as a framework(new in XCode6), the pod.a will still include in the framework, so it did't make any help.

Comment: Create a public library with cocoa pods. Upload it on the cocoa pods trunk and define the libraries you need in the pod spec file. You framework will be lighter than before.